# QObject::connect has too many arguments

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

So I'm having trouble getting connect() to work. Based on QT documentation I can't see anything that's obviously wrong with my code.

I'm not at liberty to share the rest of the code in this project, and I don't think it would be relevant anyway, so I'm just going to provide my main function along with the class header file in which my close_thread slot exists. This seems to be the only place where the problem persists.

Basically, inside the worker thread I create in main() there's a while loop doing a bunch of dirty work. That's not terribly important to my question though.

What I'm currently encountering is that when I close the application, the thread is still running and everything freaks out. My idea then was to send a signal right before the app is closed that allows the thread to return from its function and close before run time ends, thus avoiding the problems I described.

As of right now trying to connect the aboutToQuit signal in my QApplication with my slot close_thread produces multiple errors, which I've listed below.

I've used connect() in other places throughout the project with no problems whatsoever so I'm kind of confused by this particular hiccup.

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication a(argc, argv);

     MainWindow w;
     WorkerThread worker(w.ui);
     connect(&a, &QApplication::aboutToQuit, &worker, &WorkerThread::close_thread);

     w.show();
     worker.start();

     return a.exec();

}
```

Error message:

> invalid conversion from 'QApplication*' to 'SOCKET {aka unsigned int}'
>   [-fpermissive]
>        connect(&a, &QApplication::aboutToQuit, &worker, &WorkerThread::close_thread);
>
> ---
>
> cannot convert 'void
>   (QCoreApplication::*)(QCoreApplication::QPrivateSignal)' to 'const
>   sockaddr*' for argument '2' to 'int connect(SOCKET, const sockaddr*,
>   int)'

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks for you time!

Comment: What's your Qt version?

Comment: I'm using version 5.1. Just for the record I've been using the new connect() syntax else where in the same project without issue.

Comment: Could you show how you declared close_thread?

Comment: `connect(` or `QObject::connect(`?

Comment: @eyllanesc That's definitely it. The call to `connect(...)` is trying to call [this connect function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html)

Comment: I believe I'm using connect() rather than QObject connect, although I can't find any documentation on anything other than QObject::connect()

Comment: @Carl In Qt, you use `QObject::connect(...)`. Inside a class that derives from `QObject`, you can write `QObject::connect(...)` as `connect(...)`, but outside a `QObject` subclass, you can't.

Comment: I think I understand where you going with that. I'm using connect in my main function without accessing it inside an object. Which would make sense because all the other instances of it in my project were within a class.

Comment: So it should work if I simply move it inside a QObject derived class?

Comment: @Carl It should work if you just make it `QObject::connect(...)` instead of `connect(...)`

Comment: OT: Don't use Qt 5.1. That's a really old version of Qt. To quote Thiago Macieira about using Qt 5.2: "The only reason to use Qt 5.2 today is if your device cannot be updated. ... Running old, unmaintained software with possible security issues that have since been fixed is not acceptable."

Comment: @Carl It would be good to indicate in your question that you are using another connect.

Comment: Awesome that seems to have done it!

Comment: @Justin or for security\platform incompatibility reasons. Sadly Qt 5.4+ are too heavy because they rely on internal web browser engine. But I don't recommend to use versions between 4.8.6 and 5.4, they are bug ridden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by overlapping names, you are sure you are importing the following headers:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

or headers that include those headers and you are using the [connect](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) defined in that header.

You must use the connect method of QObject:

```
QObject::connect(&a, &QApplication::aboutToQuit, &worker, &WorkerThread::close_thread);
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `this->connect(...)` inside a class, that's weird and redundant. It's weird to call a static member function with `this->staticMemberFunction(...)`, and it's redundant because C++'s name-lookup rules ensure that a naked `connect(...)` will call `QObject::connect(...)`, unless you defined your own `connect` function in your class

Comment: @Justin the use of `this->some_function` depends on the taste of the programmer, for some it is fine and for others it is not. So I will not argue about it, (I agree with you about the redundancy: D).

Comment: I absolutely agree that `this->someMemberFunction(...)` is something that comes down to taste, but I've never seen anyone recommend `this->someStaticMemberFunction(...)` instead of `ThisClass::someStaticMemberFunction(...)`

Comment: @Justin hahaha, do not place the answer correctly, in my head I always assume that when you talk about a class you are talking about a class that is inherited from QObject (I'm working a lot on Qt), what I meant to use this->object(. ..) within the GUI or similar.

Comment: @Justin sometimes it happening.. Qt headers conflicts pretty much with every POSIX and X11 header I can think of... primarily their macros and enums. result of using such common names as "connect" , "free", "close", "Yes", "No", "None", "Cancel", etc.

Comment: @Swift Qt has an option to not make the `signals` `slots` and `emit` macros, and instead require `Q_SIGNALS` `Q_SLOTS` and `Q_EMIT`. That should remove all conflicts, unless the posix or x11 headers are the one defining macros and global enums

Comment: @Justin exactly that's what happens. Platform headers are full of macro definitions, they never use "const". X11 headers contain macros like  `#define  None 0`. In Qt headers None is symbol of enum. one never should try to include X11 or any platform header before Qt header, or it won't compile. `connect` is a socket function, etc... That's also one of reasons why Qt uses  "private implementation" approach, another reason is compatibility with binaries

Comment: @Swift So it isn't Qt conflicting with POSIX or X11 headers. It's POSIX or X11 conflicting with Qt's headers. Worth of filing a bug report with those libraries IMO, but probably won't be accepted.

Comment: @Justin, they are not libraries , it's core, kernel of OS. Qt's private implementation uses them , You can't say that dependencies conflict with product that depends on them is a bug in them.

Comment: There is no overlap, there is no global Qt `connect()`, it is only in the scope of `QObject`.